# Getting some data from Microsoft Graph unified OData endpoint

Tags: odata, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

1. How to count number of items in EntitySet of MicrosoftGraph, for example 'users' or 'groups'? I tried:

   - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count
     Returns: lists all users
   - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$count
     Returns:
     { "error": { "code": "Request_BadRequest", "message": "Unexpected segment Edm.Int32.", } }

Also in Annotations of target "microsoft.graph.directoryObject" which are those EntitySets based on I see that it is Selectable=false, Countable=false ...

2. Will $skip be ever available on 'users' or other toplevel EntitySet items ( https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$skip=5 ) ? It is available on other items ( https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$skip=5 ). I know about $skipToken, but it is not the same.
3. Can I find somewhere in the $metadata if property is sortable? For example user.displayName is sortable, but user.mail or user.givenName are not. This would be handy in the $metadata. Is there plan to introduce this into $metadata?
4. OrderBy DESC in this formula *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$orderBy=displayName%20desc* is ignored, it shows items ordered ASC, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not much help I know, but if you do an API call that gets a Collection you can get a count using the second form you gave in the first question.  Eg:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>/events/$count

returns the count (6 in my case, and not in JSON - the returned data is actually "\x{ef}\x{bb}\x{bf}6" (in Perl formatting)).  If we use the ? as the last separator (which is what http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters seems to indicate we should) with this URL:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>/events?$count

I just get the list of events with no count as you do.

So that seems to indicate two things to me:

a) The $count doesn't appear to work as a query parameter, despite the documentation and the OData standards saying it should,

and

b) There seems to be a bug in the API for handling EntitySets which isn't there for Collections.

Sorry I can't be of more help, but its another data point at least (I just came unstuck with the same thing which is why I noticed this StackOverflow post!)

Comment: I don't think that it is a 'bug' because as I wrote above it is specified that you can't use $count on those EntitySets. In the Annotations of target "microsoft.graph.directoryObject" is specified Countable=false.

Though, I'm wondering if you can count them in some other way then.

I can probably only select all of the items (repeadetly, using skipToken) and count them. Also - because EntitySets are not Selectable - I can't select just Id's to minimise the amount of data while doing that.

Comment: Interestingly though, if I use a (purposely broken) API URL of:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id>/$count

I get the error message:

"The request URI is not valid. $count cannot be applied to the segment \'users\' since $count can only follow an entity set, a collection navigation property, a structural property of collection type, an operation returning collection type or an operation import returning collection type."

So it looks like it is _supposed_ to work with EntitySets!

Comment: I created https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/126 to correct http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters. $count is supported as both query parameter and segment, but not for all entity types. As a note - we already support $select for directoryObject and will be removing the Selectable=false annotation from the metadata.

Comment: The error message for users/<id>/$count is generated based on OData parsing of the request and indicates where the OData protocol allows the $count segment. The fact that the $count segment is allowed after an entity set segment by the protocol doesn't mean that it must be supported for all types. OData doesn't mandate full support of all its capabilities for all types/entity sets and we use the capabilities vocabulary annotations for expressing the level of support in the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$count is the correct OData syntax (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398087), but as indicated in the metadata directoryObject collections are not currently countable. ODataV4 also allows $count in query parameters (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398166), but then it should be specified with true or false value (e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$count=true) and the response will include both the collection and its count in the @odata.count property. This is again not supported for directoryObject collections.

Ad 2. There is no plan right now to support $skip for directoryObject collections.

Ad 3. Yes, we plan to indicate which properties are sortable by in metadata using the SortRestrictions annotation defined in the OData capabilities vocabulary (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/vocabularies/Org.OData.Capabilities.V1.xml)

Ad 4. Your request is correct, but we only support sorting users by displayName in the ascending order.